# Listing subpages title and content and styling the first iteration differently

Tags: loop, child-pages

So for now, every iteration looks the same and it's been a while since I dealt with php so could you help me?

```
   <?php
$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');
$count = 0;
foreach($pages as $page)
{
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if(!$content)
        continue;
    if($count >= 2)
        break;
    $count++;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
?>
    <div id="<?php echo $page->post_title ?>">
      <h2><?php echo $page->post_title ?></h2>
    <?php echo $content ?>
      </div>
<?php
}
  ?>
```

I've look there and there and found that I coud Use something like this

```
<?php foreach ($pages as $page) : start_wp(); ?>
    <?php if ($i == 1) : ?>
 //first iteration
   <?php else : ?>
//the rest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `$wp_query` to retrieve pages and posts because it's the most efficient way and you can differentiate the loop with `$current_post` parameter which returns the index of the loop.

**It works like this**

```
<?php 

    $args = array (
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //Showing all the pages
        'post_type' =>  'page', //Retrieving pages not posts.
        'post_parent'   => $post->ID
        );

    $the_query = new WP_query($args);
    while($the_query->have_posts()):
        $the_query->the_post();
            if ($the_query->current_post == 0){ // For first child page only
                            echo 'FIRST POST IS: ';
                the_title();
            }
            else{   //For rest of the pages
                the_title();
            }
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Have a look at the if structure. You can use the post index `current_post` like that.

You can customize the query the way you like.

Reference: [WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's working after a few tweaks.

Comment: Do you know how to get subpages in the order they are in the Page menu?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a PHP question than a wordpress question. If I have understood clearly you want the first result of the loop to be styled differently from the others. This is how I would do it.

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');

$count = 0;

foreach($pages as $page) {

$content = $page->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

if($count=0) { ?>

     //markup for first iteration

  <?php  } else { ?>

      //markup for remaining iterations

   </php }

    $count++;
}

  ?>
```